# Brezis' exercise 8.32.2: given $f \in H$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a unique $u \in V$ satisfying a condition

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 1)$.
I am trying to solve a problem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> **Exercise 8.31** Let $V=\{v \in H^1 (I) : v(1)=0\}$. Let $H$ be the vector space of real-valued measurable functions on $I$ such that $x f(x) \in L^2 (I)$.
>
> 1. Show that $H$ equipped with the scalar product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_H$ by
>    $$
>    \langle f, g \rangle_H :=\int_I f(x)g(x)x^2 \, \mathrm d x.
>    $$
>    is a Hilbert space.
> 2. Given $f \in H$ and $\varepsilon>0$, check that there exists a unique $u \in V$ satisfying
>    $$
>    \int_I u'(x) v'(x) (x^2+\varepsilon) \, \mathrm d x+ \int_I u(x) v(x) x^2 \, \mathrm d x = \int_I f(x) v(x) x^2 \, \mathrm d x \quad v \in V.
>    $$
>    This $u$ is denoted by $u_{\varepsilon}$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in my below attempt of (2.). Could you please have a check on it?

---

Notice that $V$ is a closed subspace of $H^1(I)$, so $(V, \|\cdot\|_{H^1})$ is a Hilbert space. We define a continuous bilinear form $[\cdot, \cdot]$ on $V$ by
$$
[u, v] := \int_I [ u'(x) v'(x) (x^2+\varepsilon) + u(x) v(x) x^2] \mathrm d x.
$$

For $v \in V$, we have $v(x) = -\int_x^1 v'$ and thus $\| v \|_{\infty} \le \| v' \|_{L^2}$. Then for $v \in V$,
$$
\begin{align*}
[v, v] &= \int_I [ |v'(x)|^2 (x^2+\varepsilon) + |v(x)|^2 x^2] \mathrm d x \\
&\ge \varepsilon \int_I |v'|^2 \ge \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \|v\|_{H^1}.
\end{align*}
$$

Then $[\cdot, \cdot]$ is coercive on $V$. By Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, the linear map
$$
V \to \mathbb R, \quad v \mapsto\int_I f(x) v(x) x^2 \, \mathrm d x
$$
is continuous. The claim then follows from Lax-Milgram theorem.